# What is the best practice for dealing with Chrome's default 8px margin?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, sass

By default Chrome adds an 8px margin, and I'm using Normalize.css to correct that. I've also reset margins and padding in my stylesheet with the universal selector.

If I drop the normalize.css from my project, the 8px margin by Chrome is applied. Is there a way to get around this without introducing normalize.css to my site? I'd rather not have to use it, simply because it adds more work for the browser.

```
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit; 
}

 body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

Comment: simply do `body{margin:0}` ... and it's not a good idea to reset margin/padding for everything, you may get unexpected result

Comment: I'm not sure why you think this is something to be "corrected". As if it is an error on Chrome's part!

Answer (score 1):

You've almost answered this yourself. You just need to add a zero margin to your CSS.  You can do this in your own CSS, you don't need a full-on CSS framework.

```
body {
  margin: 0;     
}
```

Comment: I've done this, and I can't seem to get it to work. When I take that part out of the normalize.css it adds the default margin, even though I put the exact same thing in my own stylesheet.

Comment: OK two approaches. 1. Change `body { margin: 0; }` in normalize.css. 2. If you're using a further CSS file, ensure your application is also reading from it, and remove `margin: 0;`  from normalize.css.